# MySQL - Table code and displaying content

Tags: mysql

I need a table that will have an auto-incrementing id number (so 1,2,3,4 for each entry), a name, a time in the form of s s:ms ms (seconds and milliseconds) and a contact number.

The problem that I am having is that I need to then display them in a website showing the 10 fastest times. How do you think I should go about writing the s s:ms ms timecode so that I can display them on the page?

Thanks!

Comment: What does s s:ms ms represent? Do you mean s:ms? Please be more specific.

Comment: Do you already have your table? I assume you only want a sql query to get these times and do not need to know how to display them once you've queried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query you need. I am assuming the structure of the table is similar to this based on the little information provided.

```
SELECT id, name, speed FROM records
ORDER BY speed ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: cool so that will work if i just have 'speed' set as a integer?

Comment: Speed can be an integer, or a timestamp, or any ordered set of symbols.